# Screen element shown over the quick action modal

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-quickaction, flow-screen-component, flowscreen

I have a custom quick action that calls a lightning aura cmp. this component will in-turn call the screen flow. Over the quick action modal the screen selection element is popping up which looks very bad. Below is the screen shot : [image]

How can I remove the modal with Cancel Button and show the screen element of the screen flow with Next button?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing research on this problem, I found that we can use `force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader` in aura component.
This will remove the Header and Footer from the quick action modal.